# How can you make water a solid that is not ice

Tags: science-based

I have made water into ice but is there a way to make it a solid without freezing it or somehow turning it into ice?

Comment: Water in the solid phase is called ice by definition. The transition from the liquid phase to solid phase is called freezing by definition. I am not at all sure of what you are asking. You should clarify what you mean by "ice" other than "water in the solid phase", and what you mean by "freezing" other than "the transition from liquid phase to solid phase". (Note that water can transition directly from the gas phase to solid phase; this is not called freezing, it's called "[deposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposition_(phase_transition))".)

Comment: Solid water is, by definition, ice. You can't make it into anything else.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  Your question doesn't have any worldbuilding context --- nothing to connect it to a fictional world and how things in a fictional world work.  I think this kind of question would be better asked in the chemistry or physics forum, as it's a straight up matter of applying science to a well known substance.  In the mean time, please check out our [tour] and [help] so you can get a better understanding of what we're about and what kinds of questions we answer here.

Comment: ...Well, I suppose you could try dehydrating it, that often turns liquids into solids :-)

Answer (score 5):

There's a fine point of definition here.  Yes, water that has solidified (generally due to temperature reduction) is commonly called ice, but there are lots of *kinds* of ice.  Most commonly, when discussing other ices, we talk about "pressure ices" such as are found deep within ice moons or possibly in a couple cases in the lowest strata of the Antarctic ice cap.

However...

Normal (non-pressure) ice is defined as having a hexagonal prismatic crystal structure.  This is responsible for the six-fold symmetry of snowflakes, for instance, as well as for the volume expansion as water passes its minimum-volume temperature just above freezing -- because the crystal form takes up more space than the loosely tetrahedral arrangement of the molecules in liquid form.

It is possible solidify water without allowing it to crystallize.  This has been demonstrated in laboratory conditions decades ago, using metal plates chilled with dry ice or liquid nitrogen and slamming them together to trap a falling water drop between.  The drop freezes -- but it freezes too rapidly for crystals to form.  It is optically different from normal ice, has different mechanical properties, and doesn't expand compared to the original liquid.

What you've got here is a *glass* made of water, or "amorphous solid water".  It's ice, but not ice.